# Сервлет показывает только index.html вместо вывода doGet

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, servlet, gradle

Пытаюсь собрать HelloWorld сервлет в IDEA и запустить его через Tomcat.

В итоге получаю *.war файл, кидаю его в папку Томката и иду на `http://localhost:8080/scp-ru-1/`

Получаю только то, что у меня в `index.html` файле. Как получить вывод того, что в классе сервлета должно выводится?

Класс сервлета:

```
class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getOutputStream().write("Test test".getBytes());
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.test.scpweb.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

build.gradle

```
//gretty plugin
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

group 'scpweb'
version '1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}
```

---

Возможно, что-то не так с классом, т.к. при попытке зайти на `http://localhost:8080/scp-ru-1/MyServlet` выдаёт

`HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class ru.test.scpweb.MyServlet`

```
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class ru.test.scpweb.MyServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class ru.test.scpweb.MyServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager can not access a member of class ru.test.scpweb.MyServlet with modifiers ""
    sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Также большая проблема в том, что после `refresh all gradle projects` выполнить `assemble` удаётся только в течении пары минут. После этого, до следующего  `refresh all gradle projects` на все запуски задач `gradle` выдаёт ошибку

```
18:42:37: Executing external task 'assemble'...
CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
18:42:37: External task execution finished 'assemble'.
```

Не уверен, но кажется следующее сообщение раскрывает детали (вкладка messages при попытке `build`)

```
Error:Cannot run program "C:\DEV\IDEA\jre\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\mohax\.IdeaIC2016.3\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
```

---

**UPD:**

Основная проблема - модификатор доступа класса. У меня пакетный стоял, а надо было публичный, т.е. `public class MyServlet`.

А проблема с `gradle` была в том, что в IDEA слетел путь к Java. Проставил заново - проблемы со сборкой исчезли.

Comment: Попробуйте объявить этот класс (MyServlet) с модификатором "public".

Comment: @iTollu, **facepalm**. Вот это я лоханулся, спасибо) Напишите в ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на первую половину вопроса: нужно объявить класс MyServlet с модификатором public. Об этом говорит второй стектрейс (root cause) из приведённого сообщения об ошибке.

Насчёт Gradle, запускаемом из IDEA на Windows ничего сказать, к сожалению, не могу. Разве что, попробовать Gradle из командной строки, чтобы отсечь проблемы из-за конфигурации в IDEA. Это будет в любом случае полезно для последующей Continuous Delivery.

UPD: про Gradle, значит,уже не актуально. Но я при разработке всегда стараюсь сначала добиться сборки без участия IDE, а уже потом её конфигурировать. То же самое относится к Maven, Sbt, npm и другим сборщикам.